# getElementByID not working in angular if ng-if is used in an element

Tags: angularjs

I have  a paragraph element in html. The element is visible only if a value is true.I have used ng-if to check that. I am trying to access the element through getElementByID but it returns null.

However i am able to access the other paragraph element in the html where ng-if is not used. How do i access the paragraph element and get the value which is bound with angular directive?

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>

    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:50px;margin-right:100px" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div>
        <p id="link" ng-if="user.isAdmin">New Link</p>

         <p id="test">
      </div>


              {{value}}

            </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Angular JS**

```
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.user={};
  $scope.today = new Date();
  $scope.user.isAdmin=true;
  $scope.value = "Test123";

  var objstatic = document.getElementById('link');
  console.log(objstatic);//returns null

   var objdynamic = document.getElementById('test');
  console.log(objdynamic);
  objdynamic.innerHTML="Dynamic Test";


}]);
```

Working copy is updated here [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cmfr83dkg64W4LKEpJzh?p=preview)

Comment: Can you access it using `angular.element('#test')`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element --- Edit: also you're missing a </p> tag

Comment: If you are using ng-if and your expression is not returning true, than your html did not become the part of your DOM. Use ng-show/ng-hide  directives if you still want to make part of DOM.

Comment: @j2l4e i tried angular.element too. It did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the element before the digest cycle has rendered it.
If you change the code to use $timeout then you will see the element

```
  $timeout(function() {
    var objstatic = document.getElementById('lnkmanage');
    console.log(objstatic);
  }, 0);
```

Comment: how do i use it in the example. it says $timeout is not a function. i modified it to -  var setLink = function() {
        var objstatic = document.getElementById('lnkmanage');
        console.log(objstatic);
       
    }    
  
   $timeout(setLink, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Use watch and check for change in the scope variable.

```
$scope.$watch('user.isAdmin', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if($scope.user.isAdmin) {
    var objstatic = document.getElementById('lnkmanage');
    console.log(objstatic);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('lnkmanage')).scope().$apply()
```